# Error when putting image to UIImageView (another ViewController)

Tags: swift, uiimageview, segue

I have an two ViewController's - `ItemInfo` and `ShowImage`. In `ItemInfo` I have an UIImageView `itemImg` with image from array:

```
itemImg.image = UIImage(named:item.img)
```

It working perfectly.

But I can't put this image to UIImageView `fullImage` from `ShowImage` ViewContrloller. This code from `ItemInfo` ViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showImage" {
            let destViewController: showImage = segue.destination as! showImage
            destViewController.title = itemName.text
            destViewController.fullImage.image = self.itemImg.image
        }
    }
```

At the line

```
destViewController.fullImage.image = self.itemImg.image
```

I have an error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Please help me fix it.

Comment: don't directly set values to UI component in `prepareforSegue` method. At this point, none of the UI components are loaded so everything is nil. Just set a UIImage variable and set it to UIImageView from one of the WIll/Did Load/Appear methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `destViewController.fullImage.image = self.itemImg.image`, your `fullImage` would be nil as the destViewController's `view` is not loaded yet.

So I recommend you to use image property on your `ShowImage` controller.

How to do that?:

1. Add `var image:UIImage?` in your `ShowImage` controller
2. Assign `destViewController.image= self.itemImg.image` instead of `destViewController.fullImage.image = self.itemImg.image`
3. In your `ShowImage` controller's `viewDidLoad` method, set image to your imageView(`fullImage`), `fullImage.image = image`

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Create a property of UIImage of in destViewController and pass like this -  destViewController.image = self.itemImg.image